# Need to limit my results within a query to the max value in a certain column

Tags: sql, db2

The query below provides me with all the information I need.  However, I am getting multiple results due to revision levels.  The first and only revision for most of the resulst returns a blank.  If a quote has been revised, it's assigned revision A.  If it's revised again, it gets a B.  I'm getting results for blank, A, B, etc.  I would like to limit the query to only see the greatest value only if it's not blank.

```
SELECT
 RTRIM(CUST_REF_NUMBER) AS "PICKUP #"
,RTRIM(SN.NUMBER) AS "NUMBER"
,DATE(PICKUP_TSTAMP) AS "PICKUP DATE"
,B.DUE_DATE
,WEIGHT
,TOTAL_PIECES AS "PIECES"
,V.QUOTE_ID AS "QUOTE"
,EQUIP AS "ACTUAL QUOTE PRICE"
,TOTAL_CHG AS "CHARGES"
,B.CUST AS "ACCOUNT NUMBER"
,C.ACCT_SPELLING AS "ACCOUNT NAME"
,H.REVISION

FROM AF.NOTIF SN
INNER JOIN AF.BILL B
ON SN.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
AND B.ARCHIVE_KEY = ''
AND B.CORRECTED = ''
AND B.TSTAMP >= SN.TSTAMP - 10 DAYS
INNER JOIN AF.PROS V
ON SN.NUMBER = V.NUMBER
INNER JOIN AF.CHARGES H
ON V.QUOTE_ID = H.QUOTE_ID
AND H.STATUS = 'X'
LEFT OUTER JOIN AF.SPELLING C
ON B.CUST = C.ACCT_NUM
AND C.TYPE = 'M'

WHERE WEB_ID IN ('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX')
AND SN.TSTAMP > TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)||'-00.00.00.000000')
ORDER BY PICKUP_TSTAMP
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: The above should probably be added to the `sql` tag if it's not already on there...

Comment: And it is.... oh well, I guess people just don't read!

Comment: which database are you using SQLServer, mysql, oracle etc? you can use the row number psuedo column that is available in oracle. you have to have to confirm the what your database provides as a row number psuedo column. With it you can update your where clause with   [row numer] < table.column

Comment: from TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)||'-00.00.00.000000'), the database engine would appear to be neither sql server, oracle, nor redbrick.  It's something I don't work with.  @user2847496, does "I would like to limit the query to only see the greatest value only" refer to the latest revision or the value of the field?

Comment: Dan, I'm referring to the latest revision.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, may be:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
     RTRIM(CUST_REF_NUMBER) AS "PICKUP #"
    ,RTRIM(SN.NUMBER) AS "NUMBER"
    ,DATE(PICKUP_TSTAMP) AS "PICKUP DATE"
    ,B.DUE_DATE
    ,WEIGHT
    ,TOTAL_PIECES AS "PIECES"
    ,V.QUOTE_ID AS "QUOTE"
    ,EQUIP AS "ACTUAL QUOTE PRICE"
    ,TOTAL_CHG AS "CHARGES"
    ,B.CUST AS "ACCOUNT NUMBER"
    ,C.ACCT_SPELLING AS "ACCOUNT NAME"
    ,H.REVISION

    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.QUOTE_ID ORDER BY H.REVISION DESC) RN

    FROM AF.NOTIF SN
    INNER JOIN AF.BILL B
    ON SN.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
    AND B.ARCHIVE_KEY = ''
    AND B.CORRECTED = ''
    AND B.TSTAMP >= SN.TSTAMP - 10 DAYS
    INNER JOIN AF.PROS V
    ON SN.NUMBER = V.NUMBER
    INNER JOIN AF.CHARGES H
    ON V.QUOTE_ID = H.QUOTE_ID
    AND H.STATUS = 'X'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AF.SPELLING C
    ON B.CUST = C.ACCT_NUM
    AND C.TYPE = 'M'

    WHERE WEB_ID IN ('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX')
    AND SN.TSTAMP > TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)||'-00.00.00.000000')

) T
WHERE T.RN = 1
ORDER BY T.PICKUP_TSTAMP
```

Comment: This almost worked, but the last where statement is throwing an error.  I removed the where statement and given the results of the query, I wouldn't want the RN to = 1 anyway.  1 is giving me the first revision.  I need the most recent revision.  This is basically adding another revision field where I need to isolate the one returning the greatest value.

Comment: To get the most recent revision, use `ORDER BY H.REVISION DESC`. Try the updated query

Comment: In my answer, I switched the PARTITION BY phrase to H.QUOTE_ID so that the expression can be evaluated with fields from a single table, in hopes that it might optimize more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching this in two conceptual query steps, by using a common table expression [CTE].  First get your query results as you have been, but rank the rows in order of the most recent (highest) revision. Then SELECT only rows from that CTE that are the most recent.

Once this is done, you might move some of the joins down to the second section. I have attempted to demonstrate moving one for you, but you may be able move more.

```
WITH q as
(SELECT RTRIM(CUST_REF_NUMBER) AS "PICKUP #"
       ,RTRIM(SN.NUMBER)       AS "NUMBER"
       ,DATE(PICKUP_TSTAMP)    AS "PICKUP DATE"
       ,B.DUE_DATE
       ,WEIGHT
       ,TOTAL_PIECES           AS "PIECES"
       ,H.QUOTE_ID             AS "QUOTE"
       ,EQUIP                  AS "ACTUAL QUOTE PRICE"
       ,TOTAL_CHG              AS "CHARGES"
       ,B.CUST                 AS "ACCOUNT NUMBER"
       ,H.REVISION
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  H.QUOTE_ID 
                           ORDER BY      H.REVISION DESC)  AS AGEING
  FROM AF.NOTIF SN
  JOIN AF.BILL B
                       ON SN.NUMBER = B.NUMBER
                      AND B.ARCHIVE_KEY = ''
                      AND B.CORRECTED = ''
                      AND B.TSTAMP >= SN.TSTAMP - 10 DAYS
  JOIN AF.PROS V
                       ON SN.NUMBER = V.NUMBER
  JOIN AF.CHARGES H
                       ON H.QUOTE_ID = V.QUOTE_ID
                      AND H.STATUS = 'X'
  WHERE WEB_ID IN ('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX')
    AND SN.TSTAMP > TIMESTAMP(CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)||'-00.00.00.000000')
 )
 SELECT
       "PICKUP #"
      ,"NUMBER"
      ,"PICKUP DATE"
      , DUE_DATE
      , WEIGHT
      ,"PIECES"
      ,"QUOTE"
      ,"ACTUAL QUOTE PRICE"
      ,"CHARGES"
      ,"ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      ,C.ACCT_SPELLING        AS "ACCOUNT NAME"
      , REVISION
  FROM q
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN AF.SPELLING C
                       ON B.CUST = C.ACCT_NUM
                      AND C.TYPE = 'M'
  WHERE AGEING = 1
  ORDER BY PICKUP_DATE
```